# MongoDB (Mongoose) - Get only records where nested item is equal to a value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I searched a lot, tried several ways, but nothing works.

I have this in mongo:

```
{
    id: ObjectId("1234567890"),
    answers: [{
        id: 111,
        deleted:0
    },
    {
        id: 222,
        deleted:0
    },
    {
        id: 333,
        deleted:1
    }]
},
{
    id: ObjectId("0987654321"),
    answers: [{
        id: 111,
        deleted:0
    },
    {
        id: 222,
        deleted:1
    },
    {
        id: 333,
        deleted:1
    }]
}
```

I want the document with ObjectId("1234567890"), and only the answers with delete = 1 ( only the id 333).

I have tryied this:

```
  var query = chatbotMongoModel.find(
                { _id: "1234567890" },
                { answers: {$elemMatch: {deleted: "1"}}}
            )
```

but returns all the answers.. Could you give me some help plase?

thanks!

Rafael

Comment: Could you edit your post in order to make your script corresponding to your example data? I think the id `6166e7ef89b9f3d92b764fb4` matches `1234567890` and the same for `fluxo` and `answers`.

Comment: sorry, i changed!

Comment: If you run the same parameters `{ _id: "1234567890" }, { answers: {$elemMatch: {deleted: "1"}}}` in MongoDB or using MongoDB client like Robot3, do you get your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is using mongodb aggregation framework.

```
var result = await chatbotMongoModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: "1234567890"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$answers"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "answers.deleted": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      answers: {
        $push: "$answers"
      },
      allFields: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$allFields",
          {
            "answers": "$answers"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Note that in your sample documents you have `id` but you use `_id` in your query, they must match. Also `deleted` data type is number in sample documents, but you use string value in your query.

Running [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cvpXWRG6462).

Another alternative solution:

```
var result = await chatbotMongoModel.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: "1234567890"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "answers": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$answers",
          as: "answer",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$answer.deleted",
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JNlBVPIToEq)

Comment: thanks @SuleymanSah , i saw that in mongoplayground..it works..but in my nodejs application with mongoose, doesnt return nothing... ;(

Comment: the first solution you gave me returns error "Aggregation project operator not supported: '$mergeObjects'" and the second one returns nothing..

Comment: @RafaelSpessotto mergeObject requires mongodb version 3.6. It seems your version is less than 3.6.  The  second solution with addFields should return document, I guess you need to adjuest match query  `'_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId("...") ` like this. Try please.
Your solution is nearly same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I found a solution, and im posting here if someone needs this too...

```
var query = model.aggregate([
        { $match: { '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId("1234567890") } },
        {
          $project: {
            answer: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$answer",
                as: "f",
                cond: { $eq: ["$$f.deleted", 1] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ])
```

regards!